# Create a view of the same size of a super view in Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I'm trying to create a mask on the top of an image using a view that I set the background color and opacity and it seems to be working perfectly in iPhone 7. The problem occurs when I run the app in the iPhone 7 plus simulator, for some reason the mask is keeping the size of the iPhone 7 dimensions.

I created a custom UIImageView class:

```
class LoginBackgroundImageView: UIImageView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()

         // Set a mask on image background
         let bgColorView = UIView()
         bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.4)
         bgColorView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

         addSubview(bgColorView)
     }
}
```

The current result is this:
[image]

Comment: bgColorView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: yourimage.frame.width, height: yourimage.frame.height)

Dont know where this frame came from ? I assume you set hardcode values in frame.

Comment: Or add self.frame

Comment: Try with this `bgColorView.frame = frame`

Comment: have you tried to set constraints ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of frame try adding constraint to your bgColorView after adding it as subView.

```
class LoginBackgroundImageView: UIImageView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.clipsToBounds = true // set clipsToBounds true

        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.4)
        addSubview(bgColorView)

        bgColorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        bgColorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        bgColorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        bgColorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bgColorView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
bgColorView.frame = frame
```

Or:

```
bgColorView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

Comment: The second solution did work; however, the view is covering the whole screen and I'm using the same code to put a mask on another images that don't fill the entire screen. The first solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your `LoginBackgroundImageView` has `Content Mode` different than `AspectFit` or `ScaleAspectFit`? In this case it might be that the image is actually going out of its frame while the `bgColorView` has the proper frame.